# Regex for \begin{?} and \end{?}

Tags: regex, mathjax

I need to match from a a string `\begin{?}` and `\end{?}` where `?` is any number of alphanumerical or `*` characters so it must match for example `\begin{align}` and `\end{align*}`.

I tried to do it but I'm not sure what's wrong

```
^\\begin{[^}]*}$
```

Start with `\begin{`, following `anything that's not }` multiple times and close with `}`.

The same thing is with the `\end{?}` but I would like it do it inside single regex if possible.

Comment: What about nesting? If you care about nesting (e.g. `\begin{foo} \begin{foo} \end{foo} \end{foo}` then regexes are distinctly sub-optimal. If you *don't* care about nesting, it still probably isn't ideal, but it would be more reasonable.

Comment: Yes, there is a nesting inside the string but I'm replacing those all with '' (nothing) so I guess it should not be a problem...or?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think below regex is what you need.

`\\(begin|end){[a-zA-Z0-9*]+}`

Comment: There appeared additional requirement - if there is another `{SOMETHING}` (curly braces) after the first one it should also be matched. So `\begin{array}` should match as the `\begin{array}{l l}` - so the second curly braces are optional?

Answer (score 3):

**Your regex:**

`\\(begin|end){.*?}`

the `.*` will grab anything between the `{ }`, and the `?` means will stop when the first `}` comes.

Comment: As I understand from the question the requirement is just for alphanumeric characters or `*` within `{ }` brackets. Your expression will match any character

Answer (score 0):

{} are special characters used for expressing repetitions so you need to escape those as well.

```
^\\begin\{[^}]*\}$
```

Comment: No need to escape ``braces`` within character class. This is misleading.

Comment: Oops, my bad corrected it. Those outside still need escaping.